# Can I select the count of rows in another table that have the same value as the FK in that table?

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry If that's terrible phrasing. Basically I need to make a query that tells me the club name and description from 'clubs', with the total number of students in that club. Students can only be in 1 club so clubID is a Foreign key in 'students'.

I tried to use the below, but quickly learned I'm nowhere near the answer. Is this possible?

```
SELECT clubs.clubName, clubs.clubDescription, COUNT(students.studentID) 
FROM club JOIN students ON students.clubID = clubs.clubID
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `group by clause` with `clubs.clubName, clubs.clubDescription` columns as `count()` is an aggregate function

```
SELECT clubs.clubName, clubs.clubDescription, COUNT(students.studentID) 
FROM club JOIN students ON students.clubID = clubs.clubID
group by clubs.clubName, clubs.clubDescription
```

Comment: `COUNT(*)` is good enough here, no need to `COUNT(<something>)` .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include clubs that have no students, you want an outer join or correlated subquery:

```
select c.*,
       (select count(*) from students s where s.clubID = c.clubId) as num_students
from clubs c;
```